# How can I see at a glance which questions interest me with the new UI?

Tags: support, design, user-interface

I read the *[Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site a lot, and I have a bunch of tags which interested me, and a bunch of which (mostly related to visa issues, which unfortunately seem to be in the majority on that site) which very much don't.

In the old UI, the tags which interested me would be highlighted in gold, and the ones that didn't would be greyed out. Thus I could very easily scroll down and, depending how much time I had, read just the gold ones, or read the gold and the non-grey ones.

In the new UI, I'm just about able to spot the gold squares though I tried a few times and often missed one or two questions when scrolling down quickly when I never would have missed them before; but spotting the "meh" questions from among the "not interested" majority is *really* hard.

The conspicuous highlighting also made it easier to spot patterns, meaningless on their own but useful when I refresh the page; a disturbance in the pattern means something has changed.

How can I restore a behaviour that is as easy and clear as the old highlighting behaviour and allows me to quickly find all the interesting questions with one quick scroll?

(I'm not a huge Stack Exchange addict, but I had no idea this UI change was happening. Sorry if "the right time to comment" was not now, but I had no idea such a user-hostile change was occurring until today.)

Comment: You can't......

Comment: Maybe by using some userscript.

Comment: with some user script that reverts to the previous version

Comment: There are currently two user-side modification scripts (One userscript, one userstyle) that I'm aware of to help address this, there might be more. Note your mileage may vary with either! [LegacyQuestions](https://stackapps.com/questions/9293/legacyquestions-bringing-back-the-old-questions-design) and [Revert Top Questions Userstyle](https://stackapps.com/questions/9296/userstyles-to-semi-revert-the-new-top-questions-design). (Also bear in mind that, despite the pessimism, these designs often receive improvements over time, so don't lose all hope quite yet.)

Comment: Appears to be [tag:status-completed] but without official confirmation, I am reluctant to actually tag it.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thanks, I wasn't aware of that tag. What is the difference between that and just accepting an answer (which I will do when I'm allowed to)? Ah, see that I can't add it myself. I guess you mean confirmation from the developers that they've made this tweak and have finished fiddling with this feature?

Comment: Accepting an answer means you, the OP, found an answer you consider "done" - which in some cases could be an answer saying why something can't/won't be fixed. "status-completed" is a specific "admin tag" (for lack of a better term) which will indicate to anyone browsing through the question list (assuming that it still shows tags...) that a particular question has been fully fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to have actually been tweaked today. Questions with watched tags are now highlighted in gold as before. Questions with ignored tags still aren't made quite as inconspicuous as previously, but it's a lot better than it was. I think I could get used to this.